# How to add data to the anchor tag in HTML and access it using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, href

Following is my HTML code of an anchor tag:

```
<a delhref="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/questions/manage_question_issue.php?op=fixed&question_id=21627&que_issue_status=0" title="Fixed" href="#fixedPopContent" class="fixed">Fixed</a>
```

Now I want to add a question id to the above anchor tag and access it back in jQuery when user clicks on this hyperlink. For it I tried below code but it didn't work out for me.

```
<a delhref="http://localhost/eprime/entprm/web/control/modules/questions/manage_question_issue.php?op=fixed&question_id=21627&que_issue_status=0" title="Fixed" href="#fixedPopContent" class="fixed" data="21627">Fixed</a>
```

The jQuery code for it is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
  $(".fixed").click(function(e) {
    var t2 = $(this).data();
    alert(t2);
  });
});
```

It's giving me the message **[object Object]** in alert box. Can anyone please help me in setting the value to a anchor tag and accessing it in jQuery?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try something like this

**html**

```
 <a  href="#fixedPopContent" class="fixed" data-q_id="21627"></a>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
  $(".fixed").click(function(e) {
    var t2 = $(this).data('q_id');
    alert(t2);
  });
});
```

you can add attribute `data-sample_name` on your html element.
In jquery use

```
$('your_element_id').data('sample_name');// to get value
$('your_element_id').data('sample_name','new value');// to set  value
```

Comment: will it support all version of browsers?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
  // you can change the selector, `"key"` and its value below
  $("a.fixed").data("key", 21627); // on document ready, store the necessary data
  //                        ^-- Insert a dynamic value here if required

  $(".fixed").click(function(e) {    
    alert($(this).data("key"));  // 21627
  });

});
```

`.data()` stores a key-value pair. So here, I made a key called `'key'` and stored with it a value of `21627` and on click, alerted the value corresponding to the key `'key'`.

You got a `[object Object]` because of the same reason that `.data()` stores data in an object and that by passing it zero arguments, you were essentially storing the object associated with `.fixed` into `t2`.

Comment: Actually the value I'm assigning to data attribute is dynamic. For the purpose of understanding I'd given (21627) a hardcoded value. I want a solution which would is generalized.

Comment: No problem then also, you can pass to the call of `$("a.fixed").data("key", 21627);` a dynamic value in place of `21627` .

Answer (score 0):

One more simple way is:

1. Use id attribute in anchor tag to write your data.

`<a id="your-data" onclick="callfunction(this.id)">Fixed</a>`

2. Create a function in js file like `callfucntion(id)`.

`function callfucntion(id)
 {
    var data = id; // if more than one data, you can se split() 
 }`